# Windows Azure Worker Role Process

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to remote debug a Worker role but I can't seem to find any process to attach to. Apparently the role is in unhealthy state. When I select attach to debugger I get the dialog with a list of available processes. I can't find any of w3wp.exe, WaWorkerHost.exe, or WaIISHost.exe processes as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff683670.aspx#BK_Debugging_Cloud_Azure)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This can mean your role starts and exits shortly afterwards. You should add try-catch into `OnStart()` and `Run()` and log all the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your role is unhealthy and recycling I would recommend the troubleshooting steps at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx.  That blog includes all the relevant logs and troubleshooting steps to diagnose pretty much all unhealthy role issues.